# YouTube Data API

Tags: python, youtube, pafy

I would like to retrieve captions from a number of YouTube clips and figured I could do this using the YouTube Data API. I would also like to specify the language (e.g. English, German). I believe this would have been possible with v2 but after some research it doesn't seem to be possible with v3. Could someone please advise? After retrieval of the text files I plan to analyse the texts using Python. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you would want to use pafy api

http://np1.github.io/pafy/

the code will be like

```
import pafy
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0"
video = pafy.new(url)
print video.title
```